# How can I make my drop-down list default to the selected value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I've created a drop-down list for Gender, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pull the selected value in when I go back to the edit page.  Here was my original code:

```
<div>
    @Html.Caption("Gender", "Gender")
    @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new SelectList(new Dictionary<int,string> {{ 0, " " }, {1, "Male"}, {2, "Female"}}, "Key", "Value"))
</div>
```

I tried this from another question I came across, but it still doesn't seem to be quite right.  What am I missing?  Let me know if I need to provide any additional code.

```
<div>
    @Html.Caption("Gender", "Gender")
    @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new SelectList(new Dictionary<int,string> {{ 0, " " }, {1, "Male"}, {2, "Female"}}, "Key", "Value"), Model.Candidate.Gender)
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SelectList constructor has an overload that accepts the selected item that you can specify.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx

Comment: perfect!  Thanks!  I was just putting my Model.Candidate.Gender in the wrong place... moved it inside the parentheses, and it's working.  I went to that page on MSDN just a few minutes ago, but somehow I guess I just didn't get it.